# How do I post in yammer specific group?

Tags: yammer

I went through the yammer api's and created an simple html to post the feed into the wall.

But I have not found a clear idea to post to specific group.

I am using the following code to post on the wall.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta name="generator" content="HTML Tidy for Linux/x86 (vers 11 February 2007), see www.w3.org"/>
<title>A Yammer App</title>
<script src="https://assets.yammer.com/platform/yam.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
  yam.config({appId: "hyB2pTvrL36Y50py8EWj6A"}); 
  //]]>
  </script>
<title>A Yammer App</title>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick='post()'>Post on Yammer!</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
  function post() { yam.getLoginStatus( function(response) { if (response.authResponse) { alert(1); yam.request( { url: "https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json" , method: "POST" , data: { "body" : "HelloTest"} , success: function (msg) { alert("Post was Successful!: " + msg); } , error: function (msg) { alert("Post was Unsuccessful..." + msg); } } ); } else { alert(2); yam.login( function (response) { if (!response.authResponse) { yam.request( { url: "https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json" , method: "POST" , data: { "body" : "HelloTest"} , success: function (msg) { alert("Post was Successful!: " + msg); } , error: function (msg) { alert("Post was Unsuccessful..." + msg); } } ); } }); } }); } 
  //]]>
  </script>
<script src="https://assets.yammer.com/platform/yam.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
  yam.config({appId: "hyB2pTvrL36Y50py8EWj6A"}); 
  //]]>
  </script>
<button onclick='post()'>Post on Yammer!</button>
<script type='' "text/javascript">
  function post() { yam.getLoginStatus( function(response) { if (response.authResponse) { alert(1); yam.request( { url: "https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json" , method: "POST" , data: { "body" : "HelloTest"} , success: function (msg) { alert("Post was Successful!: " + msg); } , error: function (msg) { alert("Post was Unsuccessful..." + msg); } } ); } else { alert(2); yam.login( function (response) { if (!response.authResponse) { yam.request( { url: "https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json" , method: "POST" , data: { "body" : "HelloTest"} , success: function (msg) { alert("Post was Successful!: " + msg); } , error: function (msg) { alert("Post was Unsuccessful..." + msg); } } ); } }); } }); } 
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone guide me on this ?

I have changed the application id with the group application id as well.however it's just getting posted in the same wall with from as embed-widget.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

you will have to include the group id in the API request to post the message .. here is an example in c#

```
        StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
        data.Append("body=" + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(reply));
        // the below line has the group Id encoded into the URL 
        data.Append("&group_id=" + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(groupId));
        //Create byte array of the data that is to be sent
        byte[] byteData = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data.ToString());

        //Set the content length in the request header
        request.ContentLength = byteData.Length;

        //write data
        using (Stream postStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            postStream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
        }

        JObject jsonObj = null;
        //Get response
        using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            //get the response stream
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

            jsonObj = JObject.Parse(reader.ReadToEnd());

            //Console.WriteLine("Message posted successfully!!");
            return jsonObj["messages"][0]["id"].ToString();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This will post message to the particular group.
You should pass the group ID.

```
 <script>
  yam.config({appId: "Your App ID"}); //Your APP ID
</script>


<button style="width:150px" onclick='post()'>Post</button>



<script>
function post() {
    yam.getLoginStatus( function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            yam.request(
              { url: "https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json"
              , method: "POST"
              , data: { "body" : "Posted to the group", "group_id":"UR GROUP ID"} // Pass ur Group ID here
              }
            );
        } else {
            yam.login( function (response) {
              if (!response.authResponse) {
                yam.request(
                  { url: "https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json"
                  , method: "POST"
                  , data: { "body" : "Posted to the group", "group_id":"UR GROPU ID"}
                  }
                );
              }
            });
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Can someone please show more complicated example? I'd like to POST a video via messages.json API, I'd like to have thumbnail and type set to as video.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small API wrapper : [Yammer.SimpleAPI](https://github.com/RaynaldM/Yammer.SimpleAPI).

You can use directly from [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Yammer.SimpleAPI/)

Comment: Please add more details than just a link.